# UIProgressView Value From Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

Hi so this might seem like a very trivial question to most people but its really caught me off guard. I'm using storyboards to create my app and when a user signups for the first time they are taken through an "intro". I have a UIProgressView to show the user how far through they are and it's set in each view controller. However I need to get the value that the progress view is set to in my code and I keep getting incompatible type errors.

```
//viewcontroller.m
float complete = _progress;


//viewcontroller.h
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;
```

I've tried multiple other lines of codes, however this brings me the one with the least errors ! Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
float complete = self.progress.progress;
```

or

```
float complete = _progress.progress;
```

instead of

```
float complete = _progress;
```

Use good naming convention it will help to avoid errors and improve readability of code.you can declare it as `progressView` for more clarity

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
```

and access it as

```
float complete = self.progressView.progress;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Relatively new to Object-C so this helps clarify how it works a lot as well thanks! I would vote up the clarity of your answer as well if I had the reputation to be able to!